# Set commands as favorites in Shell/Bash

Tags: bash, shell

There are several commands I often use, some of them are longer and it's a bit of a hassle to type them out (or look for them via arrow-up or CTRL-R) each time.

Are there ways (built-in or apps) to link them to a certain key combo, or some kind of favorites manager that allows easy access?

Comment: Did you hear about [alias](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/alias/)?

Comment: Read up on `bind`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on the shell, of course.

For bash, you can use an alias:

```
alias foo="ls --color=always -l -Z --my-favourite-option"
```

Now when you enter `foo` on the command line, bash will replace it with that long `ls` command line. This is valid until you exit your shell; if you wish for it to be permanent, you can add that command to `~/.bashrc`, which will be executed by every started bash shell.

You can also create shortcuts by way of a `.inputrc` file. E.g., if you enter the following in a file `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-\M-e": "echo this is a test"
```

and then restart the shell, then whenever you hit control-alt-e, readline will enter that command.

Note, however, that since the inputrc file is parsed by libreadline (rather than by bash), it is used by *every* program that uses libreadline; so things like `gdb` and `lftp` will use it too, where running shell commands may not work.